# Is there way to run a python script in the background on Heroku?

Tags: python, heroku

I recently deployed a flask application on Heroku and the website works. However, part of my project includes another python script running in the background that scrapes data from an email server and stores it in the file system so the flask app can use the data. When I run the program locally, I have both scripts running at the same time. Is there a way to accomplish the same thing on Heroku?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One idea that comes to mind is [multithreading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html). Not sure how efficient it will be or if it applies to your program.

You can just call the function from your script under `if __name__ == '__main__'`. I just wrote this really quickly, so it might not be accurate but it is along the lines of what I wrote.

```py
import threading, os
from other_script_to_run import email_app

def flask_app():
    app.run()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=email_app, name='email')
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=flask_app, name='flask')
  
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
  
    t1.join()
    t2.join()
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried this and it does work locally. Do I have to do anything special to get this to run on Heroku? I tried pushing the code just like that and it is not working